# task library produces random results

Tags: c#

I have 2 questions about Task factory in c#.
1) why does the result in this code randomly change? Note that if I step through the code, then it works.
2) If I change the Div method to throw exceptions, then the WaitForAll method blows up. Is there a workaround for this?

```
List<Task<float>> tasks = new List<Task<float>>();
for (float i = -3.0f; i < 3.0f; i+=1.0f)
{
    Console.WriteLine("sent " + i);
    Task<float> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<float>(() => Div(5.0f, i));
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
foreach(Task<float> t in tasks)
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: " + t.Exception);
        break; // abort
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("result: " + t.Result);
    }
}

private static float Div(float a, float b)
{
    Console.WriteLine("got " + b);
    if (b == 0) return 0.0f;// throw new Exception("Divide by zero");
    return a / b;
}
```

result randomly changes. Here is one of the results:

```
sent -3
sent -2
sent -1
sent 0
sent 1
sent 2
got 2
got 2
got 2
got 2
got 2
got 3
result: 2.5
result: 1.666667
result: 2.5
result: 2.5
result: 2.5
result: 2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures.

Assign `i` into local variable within `for` loop before you pass it into the `Task`:

```
List<Task<float>> tasks = new List<Task<float>>();
for (float i = -3.0f; i < 3.0f; i+= 1.0f)
{
    float input = i;
    Console.WriteLine("sent " + i);
    Task<float> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<float>(() => Div(5.0f, input));
    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

Otherwise, `i` will be shared between the loop and all the tasks, so when loop increments it using `i += 1.0f` all the tasks see the change as well. That's why you get a bunch of `2`s print out as `got`.